# Have I managed the memory correctly here? (simple C++ stack)

Tags: c++, memory-management

I'm a complete noob with dynamically allocated memory. Will this have a memory leak or any other memory problem?

```
#include <iostream.h>

template <class T> class stack
{
         struct node
         {
                T value;
                node* next;
         };

         public:
                stack()
                {
                       size = 0;
                }

                ~stack()
                {
                       while(size > 0)
                       {
                           node *n = top->next;
                           delete top;
                           top = n;
                           size--;
                       }
                }

                void push(T value)
                {
                     node *n = new node;
                     n->value = value;

                     if(size == 0)
                     {
                          top = n;
                     }
                     else
                     {
                         n->next = top;
                         top = n;
                     }

                     size++;
                }

                T pop()
                {
                       if(size<1)
                       {
                            std::cerr<<"Stack underflow"<<endl;
                            exit(0);
                       }
                       else
                       {
                           node* n = top;
                           int val = n->value;
                           top = n->next;

                           delete n;
                           size--;

                           return val;
                       }
                }

                int getSize()
                {
                    return size;
                }

        private:
                int size;
                node *top;
};
```

Comment: `<iostream.h>` is wrong -- you should be using `<iostream>` instead. Also, this smells like homework -- otherwise you'd be using `std::stack<t>`.

Comment: Not homework; I just needed some way to learn memory management.

Comment: @eric: In production C++ code, you almost never want to be managing memory manually. You should delegate that responsibility to STL containers, `std::auto_ptr`, some form of `shared_ptr`, or some form of `scoped_ptr`.

Comment: Ok. I'll look into that.

Comment: Two style suggestions:  if you initialize `top` to null in the constructor, you don't have to handle the empty stack case separately in `push()`.  Also, you can implement the destructor in terms of `pop()`, cutting out more duplicate code.

Comment: One suggestion: Make the `getSize` member `const`, as in `int getSize() const { return size; }`.

Comment: Valgrind is quite good and simple for checking for memory leaks.

Comment: @Peter: *If* you are on a platform where Valgrind works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't see any memory management errors -- but I do see several other kinds of errors. For example, what happens when `T` is something other than `int`? :)

Also, implementing a stack as a linked list is wasteful and will perform relatively poorly when compared to a `deque` or `vector` implementation like that used by `std::stack`.

Comment: Er... I'm not sure. I tested it with ints and chars..

Anyways, thank you!

Comment: @eric: That's because `char` is convertible to `int`. The error is in your `pop` function.

Comment: @Martin:  That was just an error in the code (`int val = n->value;` should have been `T val = n->value;`).

Answer (score 5):

In addition to the other excellent answers, one more note:

```
if(size<1)
{
    std::cerr<<"Stack underflow"<<endl;
    exit(0);
}
```

I would suggest thinking about either an `assert` or an exception here. `exit` is a bit rash, but if you decide to `exit`, do not exit with `0`: that typically indicates success, which is the last thing you want in an error.

Comment: Agreed -- should probably be throwing an exception here instead. +1.

Answer (score 3):

You missed the copy constructor/assignment operator of Stack.

When you create objects of Stack::Node you do not always initialization the next member. Write constructor destructor for stack node and everything else becomes simple.

```
#include <iostream.h>

template <class T> class stack
{
         /*
          * The stack object contains a RAW pointer (top)
          * So when the object is copied with either copy constructor or
          * assignment operator when need to handle that fact. The simplist way
          * to handle is to make sure it can not happen. To do this make them
          * private (You do not need to define them as they can't be used).
          */
         Stack(Stack const&);            // Not defined
         Stack operator=)(Stack const&); // Not defined

         struct Node
         {
                // Initialize Node
                Node(Node* n, T v)
                  :next(v)
                  ,value(v)
                {}
                ~Node() // Destroy whole chain.
                {    delete next;
                }
                // Data
                T     value;
                Node* next;
         };

         public:
                stack()
                   :size(0)
                   ,top(NULL)
                {}

                ~stack()
                {
                    /// destructor is now simple
                    delete top;
                }

                void push(T value)
                {
                   /// As is the push.
                     top  = new node(top, value);
                     ++size;
                }

                T pop()
                {
                    /// The pop is just the same.
                       if(size<1)
                       {
                            std::cerr<<"Stack underflow"<<endl;
                            exit(0);
                       }
                       else
                       {
                           node* n   = top;
                           T     val = n->value;
                           top       = n->next;
                           n->next   = NULL;    // Set to NULL to stop the delete chaining.

                           delete n;
                           size--;

                           return val;
                       }
                }

                // Make this method a constant.
                // As it does not change the object.
                int getSize() const
                {
                    return size;
                }

        private:
                int size;
                node *top;
};
```

Comment: It would be nice to null Node::next in the destructor.

Comment: @C Johnson: Why? its a complete waste of time as after the destructor the variable does not exist; and it does not add clarity or safety.

Answer (score 0):

a few other tips:

instead of simulating the stack internally just use a normal list where you have a pointer to the first and last element of the list, there is no need to mimic a stack internally as long as you provide the push/pop functionality.

i would also skip the 'size' member altogether, instead just count the nodes in the list. this way you don't need to keep the size counter and the list synchronized. Just make sure you initialize the pointers to NULL. calculating size would then look something like:

```
for(Node* p=first; p!=NULL; p=p->next) ++size;
```

Comment: Well, your size calculation will work, so no -1 from me. But the performance of that is really bad: it's O(n). So if someone used getSize() as exit condition in a for loop performance would become O(n*n) ... like when people use strlen(): simple mistake, horrible performance ... try not to encourage that when building an API.

Comment: My answer is relating to OP's question i.e. memory management. You are right of course about the performance